# Why control is not going in else part and Toast, if login information provided is wrong?

Tags: java, android, json, if-statement

Here i Am triying to login. The code works fine except else part when i provide wrong information it should goes else part and toast in `postExecute`. but it does not do anything when i provide wrong password or username. please see my code why control not goes in else part? what i am missing here?

here is **json** if provide valid information provide.

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "status_message": "Success",
  "response":
  {
    "result": "1",
    "memberID" : "2385",
    "memberKey":"d69b87b2c0ad828bf7c0c30b83ea0c11"
  }
}
```

and here if info provide wrong

```
 {
"status": "400",
"message" : "Failure: Invalid App Key"
}
```

here is login.code

```
   private void login(final String username, String password) {

      class LoginAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

            private Dialog loadingDialog;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Login .this, "Please wait", "Loading...");
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    jsonObject.accumulate("username", params[0]);
                } catch (JSONException e4) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e4.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    jsonObject.accumulate("password", params[1]);
                } catch (JSONException e3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e3.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    jsonObject.accumulate("deviceToken", "2324h5gj345gj3hs4g5j34g");
                } catch (JSONException e5) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e5.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    jsonObject.accumulate("os", "android");
                } catch (JSONException e2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    jsonObject.accumulate("key", "MEu07MgiuWgXwJOo7Oe1aHL0ayM8VvP");
                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }


                // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
                String dataString = jsonObject.toString();


                InputStream is = null;
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", dataString));
                //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));
                String result = null;

                try{
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                            "http://mobile.betfan.com/api/?action=login");

                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    is = entity.getContent();

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return result;
            }




    //Here control not goes else part if  password or username invalid

            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                String s = result.trim();
                loadingDialog.dismiss();

                    JSONObject respObject;
                    try {
                        respObject = new JSONObject(s);
                        String active = respObject.getString("status_message");



                        if(active.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s+"Login successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            session.createLoginSession("Android Hive", "anroidhive@gmail.com");

                            Intent intent=new Intent(Login.this,Welcome.class);
                            startActivity(intent);

                            finish();

                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          //Control not come here if information provide wrong and not toast.
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }



            }


        }

        LoginAsync la = new LoginAsync();
        la.execute(username, password);


}
```

Comment: still not solve. @ρяσѕρєя K

Comment: When username and pass is wrong then what response getting in `result ` from server?

Comment: Use debugger tool. Put some breakpoints and check where exactly the function is misbehaving.

Comment: it return "  {
"status": "400",
"message" : "Failure: Invalid App Key/password"
}"

Comment: you are returning different key in success and failure cases

Answer (score 2):

here is answer

```
        String active = respObject.getString("status");



                    if(active.equalsIgnoreCase("200")){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s+"Login
  successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        session.createLoginSession("Android Hive", "anroidhive@gmail.com");

                        Intent intent=new Intent(Login.this,Welcome.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                        finish();

                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logi 
    Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      .
                    }
```

Comment: its Working For me now

Comment: `"status": 200` so, The status is `integer` type. How it can works for you ?

Comment: WORKING FOR ME M WRITE SAME CODE AS WRITE ABOVE

Comment: `String active = respObject.getString("status");` should make a exception , coz, `status` is a `integer` type. So, It should be like this ` int active = respObject.getInt("status"); ` and `if(active == 200){ // Do your stuff}`.

Answer (score 0):

On wrong information your statement goes in catch part

```
if(active.equalsIgnoreCase("success"))
```

Because on success you get `status_message` but on failure you get `message`.
So add toast in catch block.